# WordPress "Could not determine available disk space for updates."

Tags: wordpress

I just install wordpress on ubuntu 23.04, apache, php8.1 and mariadb. when i login to wordpress under site health I'm getting "Could not determine available disk space for updates.".
Any help would greatly appreciate

wordpress debug doesn't throw any errors

Comment: try clearing log files? it sounds like your space has filled up,

Comment: That sounds like a diagnostic message from Wordpress itself. Look it up in the handbook and the related support documentation and as usual as WordPress is free software and Stack Overflow a programming website, in the sources. Hint: This must not mean that there is an error situation, just that WordPress had let you known that it could not determine the available disk space. Recommended reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php ([via](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0c05aa75e86a6bf2f6a7ed70e6a7a67215f6abd1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php#L1977))

Comment: @delboy1978uk server has 400GB free space

Comment: @hakre there is nothing in wordpress documentation or handbook. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Shawn: Really? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site_health/get_test_available_updates_disk_space/ "Nothing" The man who searched the whole internet can say "Nothing".

Comment: the server might have a lot of space but the user account might have a quota limit, check that too

Comment: It's a reasonable question; it's a new feature and there's little info about it and creating an '/wp-content/upgrade' folder is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 5):

- create folder 'upgrade' in your /wordpress_site/wp-content folder.
- chown to webserver system account.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).